# JSPlumb Element in wrong position

Tags: jsplumb

I have a design surface that is allowing drag-drop from a toolbar onto the surface.
The first item I drag, drops to the position where I drop it. After that, each subsequent dropped item is somehow 100 (ish) pixels further down the designer than where it is supposed to be.

[image]

Both of these were dropped at the very top (different horizontal positions).
When I inspect the elements in the browser, they are both showing up at top: 2500px but that is clearly not correct. When I edit the top property in the css, the elements do move, but they are NOT both at 2500px.

[image]

Any idea what could be causing this behavior? This is having side effects such as when I click to drag an element, it is dragging from the origin where it was dropped but the actual rectangle is offset by those 100 pixels. Worth noting that each element I drop onto the surface seems to be incremented. First is at 0,0, second would be at 0,100, third would be at 0,200 and so on. I am unable to find where this offset is coming from.

Here is the outerHTML from both elements, if it helps.

```
<div id="baseActivity_171230" class="wfElement ui-resizable" style="top: 2500px;left: 2607.94px;width: 100px;height: 100px;" domid="baseActivity_171230">
                <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="toolPart">
                    <rect version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="100%" height="100%" class="wfElementOuter toolPart" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></rect>
                    
                </svg>
            </div>

<div id="baseActivity_171231" class="wfElement ui-resizable" style="top: 2500px;left: 2754.94px;width: 100px;height: 100px;" domid="baseActivity_171231">
                <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="toolPart">
                    <rect version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="100%" height="100%" class="wfElementOuter toolPart" vector-effect="gon-scaling-stroke"></rect>
                </svg>
            </div>
```